# Best way to export minikube cluster to a new machine

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops, minikube, dockerhub

I have a **fullstack application** running in minikube cluster, i'm using **docker** as a minikube driver, and it's working perfectly, unfortunately i'm still new to kubernetes, how can i run this same cluster on a new machine, i'm loading local docker images of my app services to minikube.

### **I came up with this method:**

---

1. Push all of my app images to docker hub
2. Export all my services and deployments as yaml files ( after modiying image pull source)
3. Install minikube on the new machine
4. Create a new cluster
5. Apply all declaration files
6. Exposing my frontend service
7. App can be accessed on localhost:someport

---

any suggestions of an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: You should be able to go to the new machine, `minikube start` a new cluster, check out your source, and `kubectl apply` your checked-in YAML file(s); you should not generally need to "export" anything.  How did you set up the existing minikube?

Comment: basic setup, `minikube start`, created kubernetes folder for each individual service, where yaml files are inside of them, `kubectl apply` for all of them, where i loaded local docker images into minikube docker engine before i apply all these yaml files

Comment: what i mean by export like generate a single yaml file for all services, same for deployment, in some way.

Comment: Like a [Helm](https://helm.sh) chart?

Comment: I haven’t worked with Helm before, my yaml files are distrubted to many folders, each microservice has it’s own directory `kubernetes` where yaml files lies in, i thought maybe there is someone that i can merge all these yaml files of all microservices into two, one for services, the other for deployments, it’s not an issue. It’s just for convenience. It’s all clear now